# Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my first AJAX and my first use of .php file.  I'm following an exercise in the text and it's not working.  I tried to use the alert function as many times as possible to check what is feeding in to variables and functions, but I'm really unsure what's going on in the background. I checked the Yahoo! Weather RSS feed which is supposed to give this website some information ("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=94558") and I do see the "item" tag. The console keeps saying "Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName"!! Appreciate any input in advance....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-\\W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Weather Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>


    <style type="text/css">



    html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body
    {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    a { color: #91c056; }
    a:link { color: #515151; text-decoration: none; }
    a:visited { color: #515151; text-decoration: none; }
    a.back:hover { color: #6eece3; }
    #content-pane{
        font-family: Courier New, monospace;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 23px;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-top: 5%;
    }
    #headline
    {
        font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
        color: #323232;
        text-align: left;
    }




</style>





<script type="text/javascript">

    /* <![CDATA[ */


    var weatherRequest = false;



    function getRequestObject(){
        try {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (requestError){

            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

            }
            catch (requestError) {

                try{
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (requestError){

                    window.alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return httpRequest;
    }


    function weatherUpdate(){

        if(!weatherRequest)
                weatherRequest = getRequestObject();
        var zip = document.forms[0].zip.value;
        weatherRequest.abort();
        weatherRequest.open("get", "WeatherReport.php?zip=" + zip, true);
        weatherRequest.send(null);
        weatherRequest.onreadystatechange=fillWeatherInfo;

    }



    function fillWeatherInfo(){


        if (weatherRequest.readyState == 4 && weatherRequest.status == 200){


            var weather = weatherRequest.responseXML;
            var weatherItems=weather.getElementsByTagName("item");
            if (weatherItems.length > 0){

                for (var i=0; i<weatherItems.length; ++i){

                    var curHeadline = weatherItems[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var curLink = weatherItems[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var curPubDate = weatherItems[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var curDesc = weatherItems[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var weatherSpot = document.getElementById('weatherPara');
                    var curStory = "<a href='" + curLink + "'>" + curHeadline + "</a><br />";
                    curStory += "<span style='color: gray'>";
                    curStory += curDesc + "<br />";
                    weatherSpot.innerHTML = curStory;

                }
            }
            else
            window.alert("Invalid ZIP code.");


        }
    }




    /* }]> */





</script>





</head>
<body onload ="weatherUpdate()">
<div id="content-pane">



<a href="http://cois-linux.austincc.edu/~u4744906" class="back">go back</a>
<div id="headline">Weather Report</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />


<form method="get" action="">
    <p>ZIP code <input type="text" name="zip" value="94558"/> <input type="button" value="Check Weather" onclick="weatherUpdate()" /></p>






</form>

<p id="weatherPara"></p>










</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the WeatherReport.php file.

```
<?php
$Zip = $_GET["zip"];
$WeatherURL 
  = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=" . $Zip;
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen(file_get_contents($WeatherURL)));
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
readfile($WeatherURL);
?>
```

Comment: One big thing I'd suggest is to try and use the console instead of alerts.  In Chrome, go to view-->developer-->javascript console, or you can get Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your WeatherReport.php in form action. You have to specify your php file in you action otherwise the form will point to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `fillWeatherInfo`, you haven't passed it any parameters.  Therefore, I believe `weatherRequest.responseXML` is an empty object.

In your `onreadystatechange` property, you need to pass in the parameters of the AJAX response to the handler.